# Según valor del select, mostrar y ocultar inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola buenas estoy haciendo, que según el valor del select me muestra unos inputs y me oculta otros, pero no me funciona bien, como son inputs iguales en algunos casos no me lo muestra bien.

Por ejemplo; si sale "0" me tiene que mostrar = ingredientes, individual, mediana, familiar, novedad
Si sale "4" que comparte inputs me tiene que salir: ingredientes, precio, novedad.

Pero al ser ingredientes y novedad igual que en el "0" me sale solo en el 3 y 4 ya que es lo ultimo que sale, como puedo hacer??

```
window.onload=muestraMas;
    function muestraMas(){
        var var1=document.getElementById('categoriaEle').value;
        
        if(var1=="0"){
            $('#INPUTingredientes').show();
            $('#INPUTindividual').show();
            $('#INPUTmediana').show();
            $('#INPUTfamiliar').show();
            $('#INPUTnovedad').show();
        }else{
            $('#INPUTingredientes').hide();
            $('#INPUTindividual').hide();
            $('#INPUTmediana').hide();
            $('#INPUTfamiliar').hide();
            $('#INPUTnovedad').hide();
        }
        if(var1=="1"){
            $('#INPUTprecio').show();
            $('#INPUTunidades').show();
        }else{
            $('#INPUTprecio').hide();
            $('#INPUTunidades').hide();
        }
        if(var1=="2"){
            $('#alergenos').hide();  
            $('#INPUTprecio').show();  
        }else{
            $('#alergenos').show(); 
            $('#INPUTprecio').hide();
        }
        if(var1=="3" || var1=="4"){
            $('#INPUTingredientes').show();
            $('#INPUTprecio').show();
            $('#INPUTnovedad').show();
        }else{
            $('#INPUTingredientes').hide();
            $('#INPUTprecio').hide();
            $('#INPUTnovedad').hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: La lógica de tus sentencias está muy mal, básicamente casi todos los bloques `else` se ejecutarán. Cuando tienes este tipo de casos de muchas comparaciones lo usual es reemplazar las sentencias [`if else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/if...else) por sentencias [`swith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch). Saludos

Comment: Hola agradeceria un respuesta utilizando `swith` @MauricioContreras